# Is Seller Name mean Developer / Org Name in Appstore

Tags: ios, applet, app-store

i Submit my App to Appstore but it reject and i response this message 
why what is mean this message ?
my account name: Khalid Abuhasna
my Org Name : Khalid Abuhasna
The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name “Fusion” in the app or its metadata, as required by Guideline 5.2.1 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Next Steps

Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the Fusion name. If you have developed this app on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account. If your client does not yet have an Apple Developer account, they can enroll in the Apple Developer Program through the Apple Developer website.

To request an update to the company name or entity type associated with this Apple Developer Program account, the Team Agent will need to contact Apple Developer Support to request an update to the company name. On the Contact Us page, select "Membership and Account," then "Organization Name Change" to make this request.

Note that submitting documentation showing permission to publish this app on behalf of the content owner or institution will not resolve this issue. This app must be submitted under the content owner’s own Apple Developer account.

To request a fee waiver for nonprofit organizations, accredited educational institutions, or U.S.-based government entities, follow the steps outlined on the Apple Developer Program Membership Fee Waivers page.

Comment: This means that the branding and/or meta data (App Store Connect description) are associated with a company or organisation called "Fusion" but your Developer membership is under a different name (presumably an individual membership). You should either have the "Fusion" company join the developer program as a company membership or submit paperwork to change the name associated with your account to the company name.

Comment: so if I change my account name to be  Fusion, i can publish my app?

Comment: yes, but you need to have legal paperwork to support the change; company incorporation papers or similar, legal authorisation from the owner or director of the company if that isn't you etc.